# How can I extend a function from another package

Tags: go

I'm using a package that is reading ENV from the ENV_VaRIABES, as below:

```golang
func New() (*LLM, error) {
    token := os.Getenv(tokenEnvVarName)
    if token == "" {
        return nil, ErrMissingToken
    }
    c, err := huggingfaceclient.New(token)
    return &LLM{
        client: c,
    }, err
}
```

I know I can modify it to read the key from `.env` file, using `godotenv` like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load() // will load the ".env" file
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Some error occured. Err: %s", err)
    }

    env := os.Getenv("HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN")
    if "" == env {
             log.Fatalf("Can not find the API")
       }
}
```

Is there a way to modify the `New()` function through something like an extension to be used in my golang code instead of modifying the package code itself?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by creating a wrapper function around the `New()` function that loads the environment variables from the `.env` file using godotenv before calling the original New() function.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    hf "github.com/tmc/langchaingo/llms/huggingface"
)

func NewWithDotEnv() (*hf.LLM, error) {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return hf.New()
}

func main() {
    llm, err := NewWithDotEnv()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    completion, err := llm.Call("What would be a good company name for a company that makes colorful socks?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(completion)
}
```